# I'm trying to figure out how to run a thread or activity in the background but still allow user's to use other app's

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make an app for work that acts as parental control's and control's the wifi state, gps state, mobile state, and 4G state. I need it to run in the background to check the state's every 60 sec and then change it if needed. Also it needs to start doing this as soon as the device turns on. My question is how do I run it in the background but still allow the user to use one other app? (yes i know this would most likly drain battery life.)

Answer (score 0):

The thing what you are looking for is called [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).
They offer the functionality which you are looking for. You can also start a service with the phone bootup and interact with them via IPC.

Answer (score 0):

1. Register a BroadcastReceiver to start your application just after the device turns on

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   ...
   <receiver
       android:name="com.package.YourReceiver"
       android:enabled="true" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. In your BroadcastReceiver, do whatever initialization you need and then configure the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to be notified periodically, ideally on a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)
3. Every time you are notified, start a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and do your work on there.